# find and match the pattern in shell

Tags: shell

I have below code which runs in remote server:

```
z=`echo $r| sed 's/\\$//g'`
server=`echo $z | awk '{print tolower($0)".outsourcing.com"}'`
```

here if am passing $r value as 'SCALE', I want my `server` variable finds the scale as '-scale' means if `server` variable finds any suffix or prefix for scale it should give the output. Suppose I pass SCALE to $r and it finds `primary-scale.outsourcing.com`, it should give the output as :

```
echo $server
```

**primary-scale.outsorcing.com**

Also this condition should applicable only for SCALE. Means if I pass any other string in $r variable it should not impact my above existing code. Please help me put here.

Comment: Which shell? If this is bash 4.0 or newer, then you have no reason to use either `sed` or `awk`.

Comment: Also, where would the "primary-" come from? Do you have globbing code you aren't showing us? "finds any suffix or prefix" -- do you mean with respect to files on the filesystem including that substring? There's much about this question that is unclear.

Comment: BTW, there's much in this question that you have no need to ask about. It could trimmed down to not have any reference to `.outsourcing.com`, for instance, as you clearly already know (of one way) how to add a suffix. Since you already know a way to convert a string to lowercase, I'm also unclear as to why you don't use that earlier in your process too. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- questions should have the smallest possible code that reproduces your true problem.

Comment: $r is receiving a user input which can be anything as primary, secondary or something else. In primary, secondary cases it is getting the exact string and printing primary.outsourcing.com or secondary.outsourcing.com but in scale case there are more then one entry I need to execute everyone. which matches with the scale, something like : primary-scale.outsourcing.com, primary-scale1.outsourcing.com

Comment: @Charles Duffy Apologies if I have trimmed down. But I am bit new in shell scripting.

Answer (score 1):

```
# translate to lower-case earlier, not later
r=$(printf '%s\n' "$r" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')

# substitute scale with -scale, leave other values alone
[ "$r" = "scale" ] && r="-scale"

# original, unmodified code
z=`echo $r| sed 's/\\$//g'`
server="$z.outsourcing.com"
```

That said, I might consider changing this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^ must be bash shebang; must be bash 4.0 or newer for built-in lowercase PE

r=${r,,} # make value lower-case, for bash 4.0+
# for older shells: use z=$(printf '%s' "$z" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]') instead of above

[[ $r = scale ]] && r=-scale
z=${r//"$"/}

server="$z.outsourcing.com"
```

As the new code contains no calls to external tools (awk, sed, etc), it will run much faster.

---

Finally -- if what you actually meant was to look for files prefixed or suffixed by the value at hand (and then ultimately ending in outsourcing.com), then your `server=` line is wrong, and so is my translation of that line to modern syntax. Consider instead something like:

```
set -- *"$z"*.outsourcing.com
for server; do
  [ -e "$server" ] && echo "$server"
done
```

Comment: Thanks. But in my case it does not matter if its `scale` or SCALE`. lower and upper case I am handing with `tolower($0)` . I want to do the pattern matching with scale if z=scale then in `server` variable matches all the `strings` with scale and print the result.

Comment: This is a change to your requirements; you said before very explicitly that you only wanted this behavior for the exact string SCALE. Consider editing your question to make the newly requested behavior explicit.